# Storing date into mysql using html form

Tags: mysql, forms, date

I have a html form where I require users to enter their birthdate.

```
<label for="dob">Date of birth </label>
<input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" />
```

I'm using this script to validate the form - http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleFormat

By default, it doesn't include any regex expression for date validation.So could you please help me to get date from the user in this format dd-mm-yyyy format and validate it.

Also, I've set mysql as date type so can i be able to store it by default or do i need to change its format.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) can also validate as you type and [works with Dates fields](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) using JavaScript built-in Date() method to validate. So, maybe you would rather mix the two plugins instead of customizing LiveValidation with a complex reg-ex?